Is ראשית really in construct?
There are those who translate בראשית (from Gen 1:1) as "In the beginning of...", saying that ראשית must be in construct form (smikhut). Perhaps most famously, Rashi writes:

שֶׁאֵין לְךָ רֵאשִׁית בַּמִּקְרָא שֶׁאֵינוֹ דָבוּק לַתֵּבָה שֶׁלְּאַחֲרָיו
Because, wherever the word ראשית occurs in Scripture, it is in the construct state

However, this seems not to be true. Ibn Ezra points out:

ויש אומרים כי בראשית לעולם סמוך והטעם בראשית הערב או הלילה או החשך והנה שכחו וירא ראשית לו
Other scholars maintain that the word bereshit is always in the construct and its meaning in our verse is: “In the beginning of the evening, or of the night, or of the darkness.” However, they have overlooked And he chose a first part (reshit) for himself (Deuteronomy 33:21).

I can add Lev 2:12 (קרבן ראשית תקריבו אתם לה׳), Is 46:10 (מגיד מראשית אחרית), Ps 105:36 (ראשית לכל־אונם), and Neh 12:44 (על־הנשכות לאוצרות לתרומות לראשית ולמעשרות), all of which (apparently) have ראשית in absolute form, not construct form. I can add some examples of אחרית, which I imagine would be a similar pattern to ראשית: Jer 29:11 (לתת לכם אחרית ותקוה), Ps 37:37 (כי־אחרית לאיש שלום), Prov 23:18 (כי אם־יש אחרית), Prov 24:14 (ויש אחרית), Prov 24:20 (כי לא־תהיה אחרית לרע).
Is there anyone who defends Rashi (and those who agree) and explains all of these examples as actually being in construct? I'd rather not have to ask about each example individually, so if there is one place that discusses all (or many) of these examples, that'd be great.

@User123 Not necessarily (cf. מרשית השנה ועד אחרית שנה in Deut 11:12, where רשית השנה and אחרית שנה presumably have the same definite meaning; or Is 46:10 "from the beginning" and "the end", in some Jewish translations). As a midrashic answer, Rashi says that there were multiple beginnings. But that's not really the point. Rashi says that ראשית is always in construct, and there are plenty of examples of it not being in construct.

Rashi's position seems to be that there is always an implied subject that goes along with the construct. In Gen. 1:1 he explains Is. 46:10 should be read מגיד מראשית דבר אחרית דבר. In Deut. 33:21 he explains that the reading is וירא ראשית כיבוש הארץ לו. (It's possible that he explains other examples similarly - I haven't checked.)

@Argon Thanks. Nice article, although of course it doesn't address this question.

Please refrain from using "really" in questions. What does it mean? Do you expect one true answer that everybody agrees on? Seriously, in Judaism?

@AlBerko I'm not asking for the "true answer", but for support for Rashi's opinion.

Keep in mind, that you compare sources that span many centuries and areas, so presumably, they didn't use the same Hebrew. Also, the commentators came some 1500-2000 years later and speculated about this long unspoken language.

@AlBerko What are you talking about? Rashi and Ibn Ezra are contemporaries.

Right, 1500-2000 years after the texts were recorded. From the Targums to the Mishna and the Talmud, we see many examples of sages not knowing the meaning of Biblical Hebrew words.
